# WebView crashes when I run the application on a gingerbread device

Tags: android, android-webview

I am a beginner to android and my app runs in Debug mode, but it crashes when I run it.
Here is my code.
I am trying to open a third party application in a webview.
This app uses javascript and it's being used on Android 2.3 GingerBread.

```
public class Classname extends Activity 
{
    WebView webView;
    String realm;
    String username;
    String password;
    String host;
    public String pwd;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   

        setContentView(R.layout.webpage);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
        //final WebPage webpage=new WebPage(webView);
        //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(true);
        //call url from database
        ClassName.geturl(getContext(),  new Callback<String>(getContext()){
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(String value) {
                super.onCompleted(value);
                try 
                {
                    JSONObject respObj = new JSONObject(value);
                    String apserver = respObj.getString("value");
                    //webView.loadUrl("http://yahoo.com");

                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient(){
                    //passing username and pasword  
                    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest  (WebView view,HttpAuthHandler handler, String host,String realm){ 

                        final String uname=App.getConfig().getUid();

                        try {
                            pwd = EncryptDecrypt.decrypt(function.getPassword());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    handler.proceed(uname, pwd);

                    }}
                    );
                    webView.loadUrl("application");


                    ;}

                           catch(Exception e)
                            {

                            }
                    return;
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Logcat:

```
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method name may not be null
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpRequest.<init>(BasicHttpRequest.java:57)
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at android.net.http.Request.<init>(Request.java:123)
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at android.net.http.RequestQueue.queueRequest(RequestQueue.java:333)
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at android.webkit.Network.requestURL(Network.java:191)
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at android.webkit.LoadListener.doRedirect(LoadListener.java:1371)
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:236)
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: There is a bug report on main Android project about this issue. No details on how to solve it though. Have you tested your code on multiple phones? http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11583

Comment: @ethan, It works on emulator , tablet and my phone. On one 2.3.1 device , the webview crash occurs intermittently.

Comment: I added webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true) and it did reduce the number of crashes.The device has very low memory, do you think it might cause the issue. If there is anything wrong with my code , please let me know.

Comment: The problem needs to be fixed at OS level. after carefully looking at the error log :
12-20 13:34:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(10452): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method name may not be null
. After looking at the source code, we found that the error exists in Apache.